# fluent-ffmpeg child_process and fs not found

Tags: node.js, npm, ffmpeg, webpack

I getting this error when running `npm run hot` or `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` or whatever on webpack:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* child_process in ./~/fluent-ffmpeg/lib-cov/utils.js, ./~/fluent-ffmpeg/lib-cov/processor.js and 4 others
* fs in ./~/fluent-ffmpeg/lib-cov/processor.js, ./~/fluent-ffmpeg/lib-cov/capabilities.js and 8 others
```

I'm a bit confused because if I run `npm list` I can see both `child_process` and `fs` installed.

Error is generated when using `import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';` on app.js

I've setup also the FFMPEG_PATH and FFPROBE_PATH but it is not working.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Well, yes and no. I figured out I was trying to use fs on the client side and it's not possible. @Esco